# JavaScript (jQuery?): Toggle multiple classes with one click

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks div.togglethis, I need two things to happen:

1. Add an "active" class to div.togglethis
2. Add a "show" class to an outside element div.showthis

When the user clicks on div.togglethis a second time, it removes those two classes from both elements.

I am somewhat new to javascript,  so any assistance is welcome.

HTML:

```
<div class="togglethis">Click me to add "active"</div>
<div class="showthis">When togglethis is "active", I am "showthis"</div>
```

Comment: You have a more easy way!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove `togglethis` entirely otherwise the click won't work next time. Also, I'm not removing the class on second div for the same reason, rather I'm calling show/hide as I think that is what you intend to do.

```
<div class="toggle togglethis">Click me to add "active"</div>

$('div.toggle').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('togglethis')) {
      $(this).removeClass('togglethis').addClass('active');
      $('div.showthis').hide();
  }
  else {
      $(this).removeClass(active).addClass('togglethis');
      $('div.showthis').show();

  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look at jQuery's `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass`, and `hasClass` methods (API references [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass), [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass), [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass), and [here](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)).

You would call these methods in the click handler for `div.togglethis`. Give this a try and post another question if you get stuck.