# Easiest way to toggle 2 classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

If I have class .A and class .B and want to switch in between on button click, what's a nice solution for that in jQuery? I still don't understand how `toggleClass()` works.

Is there an inline solution to put it in `onclick=""` event?

Comment: Inline JS (`onclick=""`) is bad. why don't you use jQuery to register a proper event handler (or a delegate/live event if you have lots of elements with the same handler)

Answer (score 595, accepted):

If your element exposes class `A` from the start, you can write:

```
$(element).toggleClass("A B");
```

This will remove class `A` and add class `B`. If you do that again, it will remove class `B` and reinstate class `A`.

If you want to match the elements that expose either class, you can use a [multiple](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and write:

```
$(".A, .B").toggleClass("A B");
```

Comment: what if instead of element I want to put class A or B depending on the state?

Comment: Be aware that you should cache the object you are trying to toggle rather than select the elements each time, the most common usage for toggling classes being in a click handler. ```var $trigger = $(".A"); $trigger.on("click", function() {$trigger.toggleClass("A B")});```

Comment: @mummybot - flagged as condescending. Frédéric - what if the element doesn't have any class "from the start"? that is an important state as well.

Comment: @vsync, that's another use case I think, but the usual solution works -- find a way to match the element, then decide which class you want to apply "at the start", then toggle afterwards.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Now adds and removes both classes at the same time.

Comment: @vsync and Frédéric have a good point but are being vague. For this to work properly you need your base-state class already set, the toggleClass(newState baseState) will remove it and add after but it needs to be present first.

Comment: @BurakUeda, can you elaborate more on this not working now? I just made a simple test in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2376wLo/) and it still seems to work, even with jQuery 3.3.1.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't know what I did wrong but it wasn't working when I tried. Now it seems fine. In my case, it added and removed both classes at the same time but it seems working now. Probably I messed up something else and it affected this function. I deleted my comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 46):

**Here is a simplified version:** (*albeit not elegant, but easy-to-follow*)

```
$("#yourButton").toggle(function() 
{
        $('#target').removeClass("a").addClass("b"); //Adds 'a', removes 'b'

}, function() {
        $('#target').removeClass("b").addClass("a"); //Adds 'b', removes 'a'

});
```

**Alternatively, a similar solution:**

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function()
{
     $('#target').toggleClass('a b'); //Adds 'a', removes 'b' and vice versa
});
```

Comment: I belive this way of using `toggle` is depricated in jquery 2.0

Comment: Thanks vittore. It's obviously an older answer from 2011. I've updated the syntax accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a jQuery plugin for working DRY:

```js
$.fn.toggle2classes = function(class1, class2){
  if( !class1 || !class2 )
    return this;

  return this.each(function(){
    var $elm = $(this);

    if( $elm.hasClass(class1) || $elm.hasClass(class2) )
      $elm.toggleClass(class1 +' '+ class2);

    else
      $elm.addClass(class1);
  });
};

// usage example:
$(document.body).on('click', () => {
  $(document.body).toggle2classes('a', 'b')
})
```

```css
body{ height: 100vh }
.a{ background: salmon }
.b{ background: lightgreen }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click anywhere
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to `toggleClass()` both classes individually.

Let's say you have an icon:

```
    <i id="target" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
```

To toggle between `fa-angle-down` and `fa-angle-up` do the following:

```
    $('.sometrigger').click(function(){
        $('#target').toggleClass('fa-angle-down');
        $('#target').toggleClass('fa-angle-up');
    });
```

Since we had `fa-angle-down` at the beginning without `fa-angle-up` each time you toggle both, one leaves for the other to appear.

Answer (score 4):

Your `onClick` request:

```html
<span class="A" onclick="var state = this.className.indexOf('A') > -1; $(this).toggleClass('A', !state).toggleClass('B', state);">Click Me</span>
```

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/v15q6b5y/

---

Just the JS *à la jQuery*:

```js
$('.selector').toggleClass('A', !state).toggleClass('B', state);
```

Answer (score 2):

Toggle between two classes 'A' and 'B' with Jquery.

> $('#selecor_id').toggleClass("A B");

Answer (score 1):

Here's another 'non-conventional' way.

- It implies the use of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#without) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#without).
- It assumes a context where you:

  - the element doesn't have an init class (that means you cannot do toggleClass('a b'))
  - you have to get the class dynamically from somewhere

An example of this scenario could be buttons that has the class to be switched on another element (say tabs in a container).

```
// 1: define the array of switching classes:
var types = ['web','email'];

// 2: get the active class:
var type = $(mybutton).prop('class');

// 3: switch the class with the other on (say..) the container. You can guess the other by using _.without() on the array:
$mycontainer.removeClass(_.without(types, type)[0]).addClass(type);
```