# Click and toggle between two classes

Tags: jquery

I know there's a simple way to do it, but I;m still new to js. I just need to toggle between these two classes and wouldn't know the function. Here's the markup:

HTML
    Example

JQUERY

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".item" ).click(function() {
$( ".itemcontent" ).toggleclass();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: 1/ toggleClass is camel cased 2/ you have to reference the item with `$(this)` which gives `$(this).toggleClass('.itemcontent');`

Comment: Toggle between which two classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [easiest way to toggle 2 classes in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'toggleClass' function will add or remove a single class.

So `$('.item').toggleClass('itemcontent')` will either add or remove the 'itemcontent' class to all of the elements with a class of `item`. If you call `toggleClass('itemcontent')` many times, you'll remove the class `itemcontent`, then add the class, then remove it, and so on.

If you need to toggle between two classes, you need to send two classes to the `toggleClass` call.

Like this:

```
$('.item').toggleClass('class1 class2')
```

This would toggle between `class1` and `class2` assuming that the element stated with one and not the other.

So if you want class `item` to toggle between `class1` and `class2` your code should be:

```
$( ".item" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

Remember that elements can have *multiple* classes at the same time. To start, your `item` should have either `class1` or `class2`. Then, the `item` will toggle between the two classes. If you `item` has neither `class1` nor `class2` to start, it will just turn on and off both classes at the same time.

Comment: No need to, `$(".item").toggleClass("class1 class2");` is quite enough.

Answer (score 1):

If '.item' elements having the class '.itemcontent' need to toggle this latter one upon click

```
$( ".item" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('itemcontent');
});
```

Comment: You need to remove the `.` before `itemcontent`.