# Infinite function via javascript

Tags: javascript, function, menu

I've made a responsive menu with a button. I've made a Javascript function which when I click on the button, the menu appears, but I want it to open when I click on the menu, and when I click on the icon again, it should close the menu.

Because now when I click the menu it stays opened.

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('menuIcon').addEventListener('click',function(){
     document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: use toggleClass as suggusted here in the alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7002070/5029052

Comment: @darkerror He might not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you would need to toggle the element's visibility:

```js
document.getElementById('menuIcon').addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display == 'none'){
            document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

```html
<button type="button" id="menuIcon">Menu Icon</button>
<br>
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="rightMenu">
This is the menu.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yeah bro , that kinds works but I have a bug experience. That function works after the second click on the menu icon , any suggestions?

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev I added a code snippet so you can see how it works. Also I had a typo in my code, which I fixed (which probably caused the error).

Comment: another problem appeared :D , It works but when I open in responsive mode , and then WITHOUT reloading page,  I re-size the screen , my menu dissapears.

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev I think that's a separate problem that may require a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

//try this code.

```
var c=0;
document.getElementById('menuIcon').addEventListener('click',function(){
if(c == 0){
 document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'block';
 c = 1;
    }
else{
 document.getElementById('rightMenu').style.display = 'none';
 c = 0; 
    }
});
```