# Change icon open on button bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am using button with Bootstrap Glyphicon Components and have a lots of buttons on one page, it is using collapse to show hidden section.Here is example codes i have

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sixts-section-collapse">Prijava <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sixts-section-collapse">Prijava <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sixts-section-collapse">Prijava <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></button>
```

What i need is when user click on that button and collapse is shown just to change that icon from **down** to **up**, i know i can make it globally for all, but i need to check only for that button and on that button to show another icon. It means when is closed icon down, and when is opened icon up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[data-toggle=collapse]").click(function(){
        $(this).find('span:first').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up')
    });
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(".collapse").collapse()
$("button[data-toggle=collapse]").click(function(){
        $(this).find('span:first').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Open
            </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Contents:Thank you to help me solve the problem, you're a great guy!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that it change the icon, but when i close it I want to back to original

Comment: May be [`toggleClass("A B");`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery) =>This will remove class A and add class B

Comment: #Rayon Dabre can you make answer?

Comment: @RayonDabre you can use `$(selector).collapse("hide")` for that

Comment: This does not work, i dont know how voted for this answer, the problem it just chnage icon, but when you closed it it again stay same icon??

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Can you create a working example of your problem?

Comment: @RinoRaj, I guess OP is mixing things up...I guess he is asking for something I suggested..

Comment: Yes, i need to toggle down when is closed and toggle up when is opened

Comment: @MiomirDancevic I have made an upate. Please verify it

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks for helping me understand the problem :)

Comment: @RinoRaj, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_ I guess  `toggleClass("A B");` would work as well..Not sure..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function() {    
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
});
```