# Toggle color on click of icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrows(up and down) that toggle colors. This works great except I have a few problems with it.

- when the arrow is clicked again, I want the color to go back to its original color but it stays as changed color until I click the other arrow.
- I for-loop these arrows, and for instance if I have two set of arrows(two ups and two downs) and when I manipulate one set of arrows then the other set goes back to its original state.
- even when logged out user clicks the arrow, the color still changes.

Can someone please help me to achieve the above goals?

This is what I have right now.

```
 <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <br />

<span class="col-md-12" style="height:1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; bottom:10px; padding-left:0.01em;
"><h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4></span>     <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
        $('.glyphicon').css('color', '#333');
        $(this).css('color', '#16A085');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909265/change-icon-open-on-button-bootstrap/35909304#35909304

Comment: you can use `.toggleClass()` to toggle the css class upon click.http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create css classes with the selected and not selected glyphicon colors:

```
    .selected {
    color:#16A085;
    }
  .not-selected {
    color:#333;
    }
```

Wrap the links in a div

```
<div class="votes">
<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <br />

<span class="col-md-12" style="height:1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; bottom:10px; padding-left:0.01em;
"><h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4></span>     <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom col-md-12" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
```

js:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.glyphicon').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.votes').find('.glyphicon').not(this).removeClass('selected').toggleClass('not-selected');
        $(this).removeClass('not-selected').toggleClass('selected');
    });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/duuu4c60/

Comment: thank you very much my only issue is I wish when I refresh the page, the arrow being clicked is still colored. I think I need to use cookies for this but not working...I can show u what I did, do you know about cookies too?

Comment: you can use localstorage or cookies

Comment: yeah I'm trying to study cookies now, as you can probably tell I'm a super beginner so not sure what and how to use cookies

Comment: I'm learning from other source right now http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html

Comment: I learnt django first, and started using js for my django project so I looked into that source. thanks for the link. by the way can you help me out again;) http://stackoverflow.com/users/6050147/em-four?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

use .hasClass() check to

```js
$('.btn').bind('click',function(){
  if($('.btn i').hasClass('text-danger')){
      $('.btn i').removeClass('text-danger').next().html('');
  }else{
       $('.btn i').addClass('text-danger').next().html(' 1');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="text-center" style="font-size:24px">
  <h3>Sample</h3>
  <button class="btn btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i><span></span></button>
</div>
```