# Change class css with javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How can i change  css with javascript when i click on it? I would like to change .javakast to .javakast2 and when i click multiple times on  it should move back and forth.

```
<script>
$(".ribad").click(function(){
    $("javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.javakast{
    background-color:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999;
}
.javakast2{
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:300px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="ribad">

<div class="javakast"></div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
    $("#ribad").click(function () {
        $(".javakast").switchClass("javakast", "javakast2");
        $(".javakast2").switchClass("javakast2", "javakast");
    });
});
```

```css
.javakast{
   color:red;
}
.javakast2{
   color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ribad" id="ribad">
    <div class="javakast" id="javakast">
       <h1>Click me to change class</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` in your file.

Answer (score 3):

You use `$("javakast")` and this is not the correct selector.You have to use `$(".javakast")`.Also, you have to `wrap` code in `$(document).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ribad").click(function(){
      $(".javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
  });
});
```

```js
$(".ribad").click(function(){
    $(".javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
});
```

```css
.javakast{
    background-color:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999;
}
.javakast2{
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ribad">

<div class="javakast"></div>

<div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It's weird because my other script is working perfectly fine.

Comment: No errors. Also here is some more CSS  

.ribad{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
position:relative;
border-top:solid 10px #3F8686;
width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:20px;
margin:auto;
margin-top:30px;
text-align:center;
 }

it would be impossible to not click .ribad its pretty big.

Comment: Yes. I have tryed with $(document).ready and without it. This simple piece of code worked in that same file a while ago but i removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Use your jquery method inside

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $(".ribad").click(function(){
           $(".javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The should be bind to elements after page is ready.
Here is the code for it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ribad").click(function(){
      $("javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting an element by a class using jquery then you have to include a `.` in front of it.

```
<script>
$(".ribad").click(function(){
    $(".javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
});
</script>
```

and if you are not including your script at the end of the body then use jquery `ready` method, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ribad").click(function(){
      $(".javakast").toggleClass("javakast2");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery toggle is toggling **a single class** on / off. what you need is toggling between two different classes.

see this stackoverflow answer...

[Easiest way to toggle 2 classes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery)

according to this answer you should try :

```
$(".ribad").click(function(){
    $(".javakast, .javakast2").toggleClass("javakast javakast2");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution you're after. I don't think you want to toggle between adding and removing `javakast2` on `.javakast`, but swapping between classes. If element has `javakast` then replace its class with `javakast2`, and vice versa.

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){

    // Save matches to a variable
    var classJSK  = $(".javakast:not(.javakast2)");
    var classJSK2 = $(".javakast2:not(.javakast)");

    classJSK.each(function(){
       $(this).addClass('javakast2').removeClass('javakast');
    });

    classJSK2.each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('javakast2').addClass('javakast');
    });
  
});
```

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.javakast{
    background-color:blue;
}
.javakast2{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<div class="javakast"></div>
<div class="javakast2"></div>
```