# Jquery toggling between two classes in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery) to  include a toggle that switches between two css classes: twotablecell and tablecell which are two different sized table headers cells which are different sizes in css.

When clicking on my button id: `sizeTog`, it changes the table headers class property to `tablecell` however does not change it back to `twotablecell` when clicking on it again.

```js
$('#sizeTog').on('click', function() {
  $('table thead tr .twotablecell').toggleClass("twotablecell tablecell");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="twotablecell">
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<input id="sizeTog" type="button" value="toggle size">
```

I've tried changing the element that needs to be toggled to: `table thead tr th.twotablecell` to make it more specific.

It only works accordingly when I change the Jquery toggled element to `table thead tr th`.

However, this is I have quite a few different table header columns which I want to be different sizes other than `twotablecell` and `tablecell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because on the second click the element you're looking for doesn't have the `.twotablecell` class any more - the first click removed it.

Select it by another means, using a different class which is not removed for example:

```js
$('#sizeTog').on('click', function() {
  $('table thead tr .headercell').toggleClass("twotablecell tablecell");
});
```

```css
.tablecell { color: #C00; }
.twotablecell { color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headercell twotablecell">
        Name
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<input id="sizeTog" type="button" value="toggle size">
```

Comment: So every `th` in his page will be affected?

Comment: No, just the `.headercell`