# How can i toggle a class in a child span?

Tags: jquery

My html is

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a id="@td.Id" href="javascript:void(0);" class="details">
      <i class="fal fa-search-plus"></i>
    </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

How can i toggle the class from `fa-search-plus` to `fa-search-minus` and vice versa

by using the `.details` click event?

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', '.details', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
     var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     var row = table.row(tr);
});
```

As you may notice, i wish to apply the toggle class on the selected child node and not in the selected one.

Comment: `onclick="javascript:void(0);"` not sure why you have that

Comment: So select the element. `$(this).find(i)` and toggle the class

Comment: Note that `onclick="javascript:void(0);"` does precisely nothing but add several bytes to your HTML. `javascript:` is never needed in `onclick` attributes. `void(0)` does nothing when run. If it was `href="javascript:void(0)"` it might make some sense.

Comment: Also, jQuery has a [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to toggle 2 classes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks about the onclick event. Actually i cannot see how the other answer applies in my case. Please check the edits

Comment: It is exactly what you are trying to do; toggle two classes on an element, and the accepted answer uses the same technique as the answer you've accepted here. Getting the child node (or descendent node) is also covered in other duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So select the `i` and toggle the classes with [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-search-plus fa-search-minus')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(selector).hasClass(classname)` to check if that element has one of the two classes. If so, replace it with the other.