# Icon not changing on click by javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[Here you can see the when I click on the icon it doesn't change. How to change it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIDcp.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('.fa fa-bars').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-times');
         });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="java.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/16ca663e5d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header >
      <nav >
         <ul >
            <li>
               <a >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li >
               <a>Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li >
               <a >Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a >Sign in</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <i class="fa fa-bars ham" aria-hidden="true"></i>

      
   </header>
   <section id="home" class="container-fluid">

   </section>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.fa fa-bars').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-times');
         });
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what should I do then

Comment: @shawaizminhas It has to be `$(".fa.fa-bars")` not `$(".fa fa-bars")` and then it would be `$(this).toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you have to change `$('.fa fa-bars')` to `$('.fa.fa-bars')` and then your toggleClass should look like `.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa.fa-bars').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
  });
});
```

Problem is that `$('.fa fa-bars')` means that you are looking for an element with the class `fa` and you are looking for a child of that element of the type `fa-bars`, if that existed it would look like `<fa-bars></fa-bars>`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa.fa-bars').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="java.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/16ca663e5d.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Sign in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <i class="fa fa-bars ham" aria-hidden="true"></i>


  </header>
  <section id="home" class="container-fluid">

  </section>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fa fa-bars').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-times');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Youtube can be very good, but sometimes the technology can be old or the video can contain errors.

Comment: Or hard to see the exact code due to youtube compression (eg a missing ".")

Comment: As @freedomn-m says, The reason why you got a downvote could be because of this statement `I did some changes to your code`, It can be very hard for people to understand what you changed and why, so it will be hard to learn from it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I answer by assuming that person who ask question is not blind he can see that what's the wrong.

Comment: @Neeraj comparing code character-by-character is tedious, not blindness.   For future reference, have a read of [what comment should I add to code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)  (which yours essentially is)

Comment: @Neeraj Please understand I didn't downvote you. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but I'm saying that I tried to teach the OP what he did wrong, maybe that is what got you downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

I did some changes to your code now it's working. you must follow this link [toggle class concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002039/easiest-way-to-toggle-2-classes-in-jquery) to properly understand toggle class how to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".fa-bars").click(function(e){
  
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times"); //you can list several class names 
   
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but the above comment already solved it.

Comment: *I did some changes* - would be more useful if you explained those changes.  (not my downvote)